# Filesystem watcher using node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to implement file system watcher using node.js so that it watches a particular directory for any files being added/deleted. Can somebody give an idea how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

check out [`fs.watchFile(filename, [options], listener)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.3/api/fs.html#fs.watchFile) for the inbuilt file system watching

Comment: Yeah ! You should note that `fs.watchFile` can only watch for a file, so you would have to loop through all files in a directory. You should consider using `node-walk` and/or `node-inotify-plus-plus`.

Comment: @Rahman The [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) states that you can `fs.watch` files or directories. Watching a directory is appropriate for this question: It will notify addition/deletion of files (but not changes to the content of the files).

Answer (score 5):

The core node.js watching will trigger a change event on the parent directory when a file is deleted, among other oddities. You can use [Watchr](https://github.com/bevry/watchr) to get useful events, and watching directory trees.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation that led me to https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar  :-)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, the previous answer by @FailingBullets, whilst good to know, really only addresses individual file changes. There is a package here that might help though:

https://github.com/mikeal/watch

I haven't used it yet though I intend to soon. I'll update my answer once I do.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @cbmeeks, the [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) package is worth looking at.  Its README mentions that it's used by webpack, browserify, VS Code, etc, so it's likely quite stable and painless to use.  It has > 4k stars as well, so that lends some weight to it.

Comment: Full disclosure, I haven't used it yet, but plan to.  I'm at this question on much the same track for a project I'm doing.

Comment: Doesn't work with a file system with much files or directory have large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use NSFW. It is a native abstraction for Linux, Windows, and OSX file watching services, thus does not suffer from performance issues like others.

https://github.com/Axosoft/nsfw